# what is SQLitePluginTransaction.queryCompleteCallback error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

my database will look like this,in this format.

```
id  cid values

1   1   value1
2   1   value2
3   1   value3
```

Please guide me.How should I implement it?

**My query:**

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT cid,value FROM table where cid="+cid_value, [], querySuccess, errorCB,cid_value);
```

**This is the code I used**

```
value=val[1];
var causedetails = results.rows.length;
for (var i=value; i<causedetails; i++)
{
    cidinstance=results.rows.item(i).cid;
    console.log("cid= "+cidinstance );
    var valueinstance=results.rows.item(i).value;
    //document.getElementById("s1cause").innerHTML=valueinstance;
    console.log("cid= "+cidinstance  + "" + "valueinstance= "+valueinstance);
}
```

when val[1}=0,it worked perfectly all the values were printed.

**The problem started from the following situation,when val[1]=1 or 2,....so on when val[1]=1,it actually has just 2 values.but when i printed it in the console log,1 value was seen after that i see an error**

```
JSCallback: Message from Server:  SQLitePluginTransaction.queryCompleteCallback(value1,value2)--->(the 2 values that should have come in the console log).
```

Where is the mistake,please guide me.

console.log print out

**when value=0**

```
05-16 13:42:59.062: I/Web Console(10351): cid= 1 valueinstance= VALUE 1 of cid 1 at file:///android_asset/www/abc.html?var%20id=0:181

05-16 13:42:59.062: I/Web Console(10351): cid= 1 valueinstance= VALUE 2 of cid 1 at file:///android_asset/www/abc.html?var%20id=0:181

05-16 13:42:59.062: I/Web Console(10351): cid= 1 valueinstance= VALUE 3 of cid 1 at file:///android_asset/www/abc.html?var%20id=0:181

05-16 13:42:59.062: I/Web Console(10351): cid= 1 valueinstance= VALUE 4 of cid 1 at file:///android_asset/www/abc.html?var%20id=0:181
```

**when value=1**

```
05-16 13:49:36.765: I/Web Console(11184): cid= 2 valueinstance= VALUE 2 of cid 2 at file:///android_asset/www/abc.html?var%20id=0:181

05-16 13:49:36.769: I/Web Console(11184): JSCallback: Message from Server:  SQLitePluginTransaction.queryCompleteCallback('1368692376635000','1368692376639000', [{"value":"VALUE 1","id":"5","cid":"2"},{"value":"VALUE 2","id":"6","cid":"2"}]); at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3726
```

SCRIPT in cordova2.1.js is

```
function startXhr() {
    // cordova/exec depends on this module, so we can't require cordova/exec on the module level.
    var exec = require('cordova/exec'),
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (!xmlhttp) {
            return;
        }        
if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4){
                    // If callback has JavaScript statement to execute
                    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {

                        // Need to url decode the response
                        var msg = decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            try {
                                var t = eval(msg);
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                                // If we're getting an error here, seeing the message will help in debugging
    LINE 3726==>                console.log("JSCallback: Message from Server: " + msg);
                                console.log("JSCallback Error: "+e);
                            }
                        }, 1);
                        setTimeout(startXhr, 1);
                    }
```

**The Problem is,I am getting the values when I get the message from the server as JS Callback. not from the for loop**

CAN SOMEONE HELP ME OUT WITH THIS???,PLEASE